# In bst file, check if variable contains string

Tags: bibtex

I have a bst file that handles a "collaboration" field in a bib entry as follows:

```
@article{test,
      author         = "Smith, J.",
      title          = "The Foo Title",
      collaboration  = "BAR",
      journal        = "Stack",
      volume         = 0,
      pages          = "1-10",
      year           = 2013
}
```

Yields:

```
J. Smith (BAR Collaboration), The Foo Title, Stack 0, 1–10 (2013).
```

This is fine, except for entries in which the "collaboration" field already contains the word collaboration.

My question is, *is there a simple way in which to modify the function below such that the "Collaboration" or "Collaborations" string is only added when required?*

The modified function would need to be case insensitive and also insensitive to singular/plural.

Here is the current function:

```
FUNCTION {format.collaboration}
{ collaboration empty$
    { "" }
    { collaboration num.names$ #1 >
        {" (" collaboration * " Collaborations)" * }
        {" (" collaboration * " Collaboration)" * }
    if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Unfortunately, the reverse polish format of bibtex makes the learning curve so steep that the [Tame the BeaST](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) document and its examples are not really helping me.

By the time I figure out a fix, I could have just changed all of my bib entries to be compliant. But going forward, it would be nice to have a function so I don't have to worry about it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the string "Collaboration(s)" appear only at the beginning of the `collaboration` field, or can it be anywhere?

Comment: "Collaboration(s)" can be anywhere. Often, Inspire will return a field like `collaboration  = "BAR collaboration"` rather than `collaboration  = "BAR"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use the `string.length` function from Tame the Beast, the `or` function should be contained in your `bst` file already. Then we define a simple search function that tests whether a string is contained in another string. Using this, we can test for "collaboration" and "Collaboration" in the `collaboration` field. Note that we do not need to test for the plural forms, as searching for the singular form will find those plurals, too.

```
INTEGERS{ l }
FUNCTION{ string.length }
{
  #1 'l :=
  {duplicate$ duplicate$ #1 l substring$ = not}
    { l #1 + 'l :=}
  while$
  pop$ l
}

INTEGERS {find.length search.start search.end done}
STRINGS {find.string find.pattern}
FUNCTION {contains}
{
  'find.pattern :=
  'find.string :=
  find.pattern string.length 'find.length :=
  #1 'search.start :=
  find.string string.length find.length - #2 + 'search.end :=
  #0 'done :=
  { search.start search.end < }
  {
    find.string search.start find.length substring$ find.pattern =
      { 
        #1 'done :=
        search.end 'search.start :=%% stop searching
      }
      { #1 search.start + 'search.start := }
    if$
  }
  while$
  done
}

FUNCTION {format.collaboration}
{ collaboration empty$
    { "" }
    { collaboration num.names$ #1 >
        { " (" collaboration *
          collaboration "collaboration" contains
          collaboration "Collaboration" contains or
            { ")" * }
            { " Collaborations)" * }
          if$
        }
        { " (" collaboration *
          collaboration "collaboration" contains
          collaboration "Collaboration" contains or
            { ")" * }
            { " Collaboration)" * }
          if$
        }
    if$
    }
  if$
}
```

As a final note I would advice against those hacks, and change the `bib` file instead. BibTeX is meant to just format the bibliography, not to alter the content. If you would like to use another style, or switch to `biblatex`, those inconsistent BibTeX entries come back to bite you, again.