# Bibtex Style File (.bst) print string only if an optional field is present

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have the following function in my BST file.

```
FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              % puts year
  output.year.check                     % after author(s)
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" output.check
  address output
%  format.date "year" output.check      % don't check for year here because
  format.date  output                   % puts year after author(s)
  new.block
  pages output                          %JOURNAL wants this
  "pages"
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

The journal wants total pages where available.  Right now it prints out the word "pages" after each entry, regardless of if the corresponding .bib item has an entry for the PAGES = {} field.

How can I make it so it  only prints the word "pages" when the PAGES field in the .bib file is declared?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles/13076#13076 or this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119237/in-bst-file-check-if-variable-contains-string?rq=1

Comment: You shouldn't modify the bst file in this way. (The `pages` field should probably be employed primarily for entries of type `@article` or `@incollection`.)  Instead, you should make use of the `note`  field, as in `note = "72 pages total",` -- or whatever the correct format may be.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of that!